# Login form validation message

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, authentication

Whenever I try to login with incorrect information I don't get the error message, It just resets my form when I try to login with incorrect information. I think I might have a conflicting code somewhere. Is there something wrong with my code? Or if possible is there any other way to provide validation based on my code?

Everything works fine. I just need the validation.

My PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

//Include the database connection file
include "database_connection.php";

//Check to see if the submit button has been clicked to process data
if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == "yes")
{
    //Variables Assignment
    $username = trim(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
    $user_password = trim(strip_tags($_POST['passwd']));


    $validate_user_information = mysql_query("select * from `signup_and_login_users_table` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' and `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_password)."'");

    //Validate against empty fields
    if($username == "" || $user_password == "")
    {
        $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, all fields are required to log into your account. Thanks.</div><br>';
    }
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($validate_user_information) == 1) //Check if the information of the user are valid or not
    {
        //The submitted info of the user are valid therefore, grant the user access to the system by creating a valid session for this user and redirect this user to the welcome page
        $get_user_information = mysql_fetch_array($validate_user_information);
        $_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"] = $username;
        $_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"] = strip_tags($get_user_information["fullname"]);
        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        //The submitted info the user are invalid therefore, display an error message on the screen to the user
        $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, you have provided incorrect information. Please enter correct user information to proceed. Thanks.</div><br>';
    }

}
?>
```

My form:

```
<div class="login">
    <font color="black" size="5"><p>Employee Login</p></font>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="yes">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Login</button>
        <p></p>
        <a href="index.php"><img src="img/homebutton.png" height="35px" width="35px">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `MySQL` functions are deprecated and removed in `PHP 7.0`. Please switch to using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). They support [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Which make protecting from SQL attacks much easier.

Comment: How does that work? Do I only have to add i in mysql statements and that's it?

Comment: No. there's been a lot of stuff wrong with the `MySQL` functions for a **long** time. Please check that documentation when you have time and learn the new method to connect and execute. It won't take long to learn.

Comment: the issue with your code above is likely to do with this `echo $_SERVER['php_self']` it may be better to build functions and use the `return` to echo those out. Looks like this could use a rewrite.

Comment: why do you insist on using this code? It's totally unsafe and is bad practice to keep going with this. Even the escaping function you're using can be bypassed and you should be using a prepared statement along with `password_hash()/password_verify()`. Are you intending on going live with this or is this for academic purposes? @JoeF

Comment: @Fred-ii- No I'm not, really. It's just for my academic purposes. And I just knew that the functions are deprecated.

Comment: @Fred-ii- By the way, can you tell me exactly how this can be bypassed...

Comment: Google "is mysql_real_escape_string safe to use?" ;-) I rather *you* go and find the link for that Q&A that's on Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use `mysqli` functions not `mysql` because they are now deprecated.

Secondly, the reason you are not getting the error message is because you have not printed the error message. You should add `echo $error;` after you defined your `error` variable